# Alexa skill to control logitech squeezebox - request to modify code

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, squeezebox

I've been trying to set up an alexa application called muzak - https://github.com/lordpengwin/muzak -  which allows control of logitech squeezeboxes using Echo.

The code works fine, but the play function is set to select random tracks which is not that helpful.

I'd like to be able to use the play function to simply play (or toggle/pause) whatever is on the current playlist.

It can't be that much of a change required to the code to allow this, presumably changing the randomPlay piece in line 254 of the muzak.js https://github.com/lordpengwin/muzak/blob/master/muzak.js file. I've tried changing this to play, pause, toggle etc. but none of those seem to work.

Grateful for any suggestions on how the code could be updated to allow current playlist to be played.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you have any luck (yet)?

Comment: FWIW having played with various options, I've open-sourced my own solution to this now: https://github.com/declension/squeeze-alexa

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a chance to test this out yet, but...

It's probably [`play(callback)`](https://github.com/lordpengwin/squeezenode/blob/master/squeezeplayer.js#L103) and [`pause(callback)`](https://github.com/lordpengwin/squeezenode/blob/master/squeezeplayer.js#L112) you want to use. Should be pretty simple - remember to remove that first parameter though, as it's not needed for these functions.

See the [example of `play(callback)`](https://github.com/lordpengwin/squeezenode/blob/master/demo/demo.js#L149).